# only allow specific patterns with specific characters regex - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a method to check if input matches either

```
>=n, >n, <n, <=n or n..n.
```

Regex has always been something that's been confusing. I feel this would be a good example to understand it better.

so far I'm just checking if it has those characters

```
const text = '>2';
const regex = /^[<>=.0-9]|g/i;
console.log(regex.test(text));
```

how do I create a regex that'll only allow those specific patterns / quantifiers? eg. `>5` is valid but `5>` is not.

what's the terminology behind these types of things?

Comment: You can use: `/^[<>]=?\d+\.?\d*$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mind the order and be more exact:

```
^(?:>|<|>=|<=)(?:[1-9]\d*|0)$
```

- `(?:>|<|>=|<=)` is the set of valid operators
- `(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)` is the number without leading zero

So the full `regex` variable would be initialized as:

```
regex = /^(?:>|<|>=|<=)(?:[1-9]\d*|0)$|g/i;
```

---

You have included to match `n..n` as an alternative. Here you go:

```
^((>|<|>=|<=)|([1-9]\d*|0)\.\.)([1-9]\d*|0)$
```

- `\.` matches the `.` dot literally and must be escaped

Test it:

```js
regex = /^((>|<|>=|<=)|([1-9]\d*|0)\.\.)([1-9]\d*|0)$|g/i;

array = new Array();

array[0] = ">2";    // valid
array[1] = ">0";    // valid
array[2] = "2..3"   // valid
array[3] = "=2";    // invalid
array[4] = ">01";   // invalid
array[5] = "2>";    // invalid

array.forEach(item => console.log(regex.test(item)));
```

---

If you don't mind the leading zero, simply use the:

```
^((>|<|>=|<=)|\d*\.\.)\d*$
```

Comment: how about for n..n?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either `>` or `<` followed by an optional `=` or match a digit followed by 2 dots.

After the alternation you could match a digit.

`^(?:[<>]=?|\d\.\.)\d$`

That will match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[<>]=?` Match < or > or optional =
  - `|` Or
  - `\d\.\.` Match a digit and 2 dots
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\d` Match a digit
- `$` Assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mqE8cs/1)

```js
const strings = [
  ">=3",
  ">3",
  "<2",
  "<=3",
  "5..5",
  "5>"
];
let pattern = /^(?:[<>]=?|\d\.\.)\d$/;
strings.forEach(s => {
  console.log(pattern.test(s));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `^[<>]=?\d+$`

- `^` match from the beginning of the string
- `[<>]` mandatory greater or less mark
- `=?` optional equal mark
- `\d+` any number of digits
- `$` match till the end of the string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z42JeZ/4)